# How can I acheive designs that are similar to this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, art

Can someone please explain to me how I can reach similar results like the pics below? Or give me some instructions? Would be nice, because I have no idea.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: what is that, a photography? an art installation? Can you [edit] your question to give us more context / details? Check [ask] to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually referred to as *solarization* or a *Sabattier effect*.

The way you might do this in a photo-editing application is to "edit the curve." In Photoshop, this would be using a curves adjustment layer and then just going wild with the curve presented.